# meaning of 言いきれる

Tags: meaning, grammar

I understand that きる　means to do something completely but I do not understand in the context.
Does 言いきれる mean: I can say with confidence ?

> 「Ｂクラスに知り合いは？」 「いるよ。仲良くなったって**言いきれる**のはまだ数人だけど
>
> “Do you know anyone in Class B?” “I do. I’ve only gotten to know a few
> people, though,”

Comment: You pretty much guessed it. "I can confidently say..." "It's safe to say..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 言い切る means "to say firmly" or "to say with confidence". It sometimes means "to say until the end", too. 仲良くなる is closer to "to make friends with" rather than "to get to know".

> いるよ。仲良くなったって言いきれるのはまだ数人だけど。
>
> I do. There are only a few people that I can (safely) say I made friends with, though.